# Accessing the value of a specific index of a list for use in an IF statement (Freemarker)

Tags: freemarker, bfo

I am attempting to access the value of the current index of the list object dfeNumber, check if it is the first instance of this number, and add a visual break.  I have never worked in Freemarker before (primarily the surrounding css), and have spent a bit of time looking through the Apache manual, but I cannot find an example of this kind of usage. I think it would look similar to:

```
<#assign msaReached=0>

<#list invName as invNames>

<#if ${dfeNumber[invNames_index]} = "900"> 
  <#assign msaReached++>
  <#if msaReached=1>
    -- do stuff --
  </#if>
</#if>
```

Would anyone be able to point me to an example of the syntax for usage in scenario?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I realized I never used this combination:

```
<#if dfeNumber[invNames_index] = "900">
```

Which worked.

Comment: The documentation of `#if` says you need to put an "Expression evaluates to a boolean value" there, and then there's also a chapter about Expressions. Putting the two together, you get this, among others. Also, don't use old FreeMarker versions. For a while you get this error message, which would have save your time: `You can't use "${" here as you are already in FreeMarker-expression-mode. Thus, instead of ${myExpression}, just write myExpression. (${...} is only needed where otherwise static text is expected, i.e, outside FreeMarker tags and ${...}-s.)`.

Comment: Also for future readers, if `dfeNumber[invNames_index]` is a number (as opposed to a string that looks like a number), then use `= 900`, without the `"`. (Also `==` is the canonical form, though `=` does the same here for backward compatibility.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I was able to locate the error message in the log files after redirecting them to a flat file vs. using the console.  That is what clued me in to the correct syntax.  Also, thanks for the tip about "==" as well.